# Dynamically generating WSDL - not working

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a web service and was following instructions on official Spring documentation pages: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ . I configured all the elements that were stated in this tutorial, but on the last step, when I tried to generate my WSDL I get the 404 Error on server. I am using STS Spring version 4.2.6, Maven and Tomacat 8. Under is my configuration:

RegisterUser.xsd - schema that I am trying to generate my WSDL from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/RegisterUser" 
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/RegisterUser" >
<xsd:element name="RegisterUserRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="User">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="userName"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="userLastName"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="address"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="age"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="RegisterUserResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="Status"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestService</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.hr"/>

  <sws:annotation-driven/>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="registerUser"                                                                                         
    portTypeName="Test"                                                                                      
    locationUri="/TestService/"                                                                              
    targetNamespace="http://com/hr">                                                       
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/RegisterUser.xsd"/>                                                                      
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

</beans>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestService</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>

    <org.springframework.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.registry/jaxr-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.registry</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxr-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring/jaxws-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>


</dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am trying to get my wsdl file on http://localhost:8080/TestService/registerUser.wsdl, but I am getting error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
```

Comment: Is your application deployed at `/TestService` or at the root?

Comment: Application is deployed at /TestService, I tried to modify spring-ws-servlet.xml, but didn't manage to find a solution so far. Anyone has any ideas on this one or it is to general problem, like NullPointerException :D